# Up to homotopy principal bundle

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, fibration

A principal bundle (say, in the category of topological spaces and topological groups) induces homeomorphisms on the fibers. This works well for groups $G$. I am wondering if there is an analogue for "principal bundles up to homotopy". Such a structure would only have homotopic fibers. I would also expect this construction to work for higher groupoids. There would be a classifying space $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{G})$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is some kind of higher groupoid, and where maps $X \rightarrow \mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{G})$ correspond to having $\mathcal{G}$ act on the fibers. (seems related to the suspension functor, perhaps?).

Comment: Are you familiar with fibrations?

Comment: To add a little more: a fiber bundle with fiber F, with no comment on the structure group, is equivalent to a principal homeo(F) bundle. A fibration with fiber homotopy equivalent to F is equivalent to a hAut(F) bundle (where hAut is the (almost) group of homotopy equivalences). If you wish to restrict the type of homotopy equivalences you use (perhaps analogous to restricting the structure group), you should pick some grouplike submonoid of hAut(F) and consider those principal bundles. Then you can replace the fiber to get an hAut(F) bundle which is equivalent to a fibration.

Comment: Every (nice) path-connected space $Y$ is the classifying space of its loop space $Y \cong B \Omega Y$ and so classifies "homotopy principal $\Omega Y$-bundles." Given a classifying map $f : X \to Y$ the corresponding homotopy bundle is given by taking homotopy fibers: see, for example, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+sequence .